# iterate through regex results vimscript

Tags: vim

In vimscript, how can I iterate through all the matches of a regex in the current file and then run a shell command for each result?

I think this is a start but I cant figure out how to feed it the whole file and get each match.

```
while search(ENTIRE_FILE, ".*{{\zs.*\ze}}", 'nw') > 0
    system(do something with THIS_MATCH)
endwhile
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we have a file with the content:

```
123 a shouldmatch
456 b shouldmatch
111 c notmatch
```

And we like to match

```
123 a shouldmatch
456 b shouldmatch
```

with the regex

```
.*shouldmatch
```

If you only have one match per line you can use `readfile()` and afterwards loop through the lines and check each line with `matchstr()`. [1]

```
function! Test001()
  let file = readfile(expand("%:p")) " read current file
  for line in file
    let match = matchstr(line, '.*shouldmatch') " regex match
    if(!empty(match))
      echo match
      " your command with match
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
```

You can put this function in your `~/.vimrc` and call it with `call Test001()`.

[1] http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#matchstr%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subtitute()` instead. For instance...

```
call substitute(readfile(expand('%')), '.*{{\zs.*\ze}}', 
    \ '\=system("!dosomething ".submatch(1))', 'g')
```